# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient with gzip

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

How can you use Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient with gzip?

Currently focusing on Windows 10 application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just works.

Just make sure the request contains the following header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

And I think it does by default.

You can disable GZIP decompression by creating a `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` with `AutomaticDecompression` set to `false`.

Comment: thank you!  Didn't expect that...  maybe you can add this to your answer. httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new HttpContentCodingWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip, deflate"));

Comment: Yes, I just just verified this with Fiddler, the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient has `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` by default.